# Is there an easy way to make an app using only SVG file assets?

Tags: react-native, svg, expo

I am currently creating a React Native app and I'm wanting to create SVG pixel art as the entirety (or majority) of the assets. I'm currently running into a problem where dynamic phone sizes are going to become an issue if I don't start accounting for them in my design.

What might be the best way to accomplish this task? I'm currently also using Expo with the app that I'm building, but I left this question intentionally broad since I am very new to the app development world.

Comment: What is your problem ?
Share code and describe detailed what went wrong

Comment: We need an example of how you created the UI, something that illustrates the issue.